# Why is getline not working towards the top of my program, but is working in another function?

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin, getline

I'm working on a program which loops until the user enters a character other than `y` or `Y` to stop it. I am using `std::getline()`, since I need to get an entire line of text from the user in another function, and it is working fine in that function of my program. It is not working when asking the user for a character to continue or stop, though. I am presented with a compiler error:

> No matching function for call to 'getline'

I am using `std::getline()`, because `std::cin` and `std::getline()` together can cause unwanted behavior. I do not know how to fix this issue and would appreciate some help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

static int ASCII_OFFSET = 48;
//48 is the ASCII value for char '0', so we take the ASCII value of char '0' and subtract 48 to get the integer 0

void postCalculator();

int main()
{
    char again = 'y';
    while(again == 'y'||again == 'Y')
    {
        postCalculator();
        cout << "Type 'Y' or 'y' to continue, or type any other letter to quit:";
        getline(cin, again);
    }
}

/////
///// the line:       getline(cin, again);         is the issue
/////

void postCalculator()
{
    string equation;
    stack<int> stack1;
    int a, b, c, holder;

    cout << "Please enter the RPN expression to be calculated:" << endl;
    getline(cin, equation);

    for(int i = 0; i < equation.length(); i++)
    {
        if(equation[i] >= '0' && equation[i] <= '9')
        {
            holder = static_cast<int>(equation[i]) - ASCII_OFFSET;
            cout << "Token = " << holder << ", ";
            stack1.push(holder);
            cout << "Push " << holder << endl;
        }
        else if(i == ' ')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if(equation[i] == ':')
        {
            break;
        }

        if(equation[i] == '-')
        {
            cout << "Token = -, ";
            a = stack1.top();
            stack1.pop();
            cout << "Pop " << a << " ";
            b = stack1.top();
            stack1.pop();
            cout << "Pop " << b << " ";

            c = b - a;

            stack1.push(c);
            cout << "Push " << c << endl;
        }
        else if(equation[i] == '*')
        {
            cout << "Token = *, ";
            a = stack1.top();
            stack1.pop();
            cout << "Pop " << a << " ";
            b = stack1.top();
            stack1.pop();
            cout << "Pop " << b << " ";

            c = b * a;

            stack1.push(c);
            cout << "Push " << c << endl;
        }
        else if(equation[i] == '/')
        {
            cout << "Token = /, ";
            a = stack1.top();
            stack1.pop();
            cout << "Pop " << a << " ";
            b = stack1.top();
            stack1.pop();
            cout << "Pop " << b << " ";

            c = b / a;

            stack1.push(c);
            cout << "Push " << c << endl;
        }
        else if(equation[i] == '+')
        {
            cout << "Token = +, ";
            a = stack1.top();
            stack1.pop();
            cout << "Pop " << a << " ";
            b = stack1.top();
            stack1.pop();
            cout << "Pop " << b << " ";

            c = b + a;

            stack1.push(c);
            cout << "Push " << c << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "Token = Pop " << stack1.top() << endl << endl;
    stack1.pop();
}
```

I have tried using `std::cin` instead of `std::getline()`, as well as `std::cin.clear()`, though I do not fully understand the behavior, and have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of explaining in a comment what `48` is, just replace `48` with `'0'` in the actual code.

Comment: getline() takes an object of type string (or other flavor of basic_string) by reference as its 2nd parameter, not a char. Also, remember it expects a '\n' or specified delimiter.

Comment: `getline` reads a string, not a char, there is no `getline` function that reads a char so the compiler is telling you it can't find the function you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can't read a single `char` using `std::getline()`, it works only with `std::(basic_)string` types.  So, you will have to either:

- change `char again` to `std::string again`, eg:

```
int main()
{
    ...
    string again;
    do
    {
        ...
    }
    while (getline(cin, again) &&
          (again == "y" || again == "Y"));
    ...
}
```

- use `operator>>` instead of `std::getline()`, eg:

```
...
#include <limits>
...

int main()
{
    ...
    char again;
    do
    {
        ...
        if (!(cin >> again)) break;
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y');
    ...
}
```